# Concerning the limit of an infinite array.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Is the Following argument correct?

> Given a doubly indexed array $a_{mn}$ where $m,n\in\mathbf{N}$.
>   Assume that $\lim_{m,n\to\infty}a_{mn} = a$, and given that for each
>   fixed $m\in\mathbf{N}$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_{mn}) =  b_{m}$. Show
>   that $\lim_{m\to\infty}b_m = a$.

*Proof.* Let $\epsilon>0$, since $\lim_{m,n\to\infty}a_{mn} = a$ there exists an $M\in\mathbf{N}$ such that 
$\forall m,n\ge M\left(|a_{mn}-a|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right)$. Now let $m\ge M$, from hypothesis $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{mn} = b_m$ and thus for some $N\in\mathbf{N}$ we have $|a_{mn}-b_m|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ whenever $n\ge N$.

Now let $L = \max(M,N)$ and $n\ge L$ then we have $|b_m-a_{mn}|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $|a_{mn}-a|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, appealing to the triangle inequality we have $$|b_m-a| = |(b_m-a_{mn})+(a_{mn}-a)|\leq|b_{m}-a_{mn}|+|a_{mn}-a|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$$

$\blacksquare$

**PS:** We define $\lim_{m,n\to \infty}(a_{mn})=a$ if and only if $\forall\epsilon>0\exists M\in\mathbf{N}\forall m,n\ge M(|a_{mn}-a|<\epsilon)$.

Comment: This proof is incorrect in that $N$ actually depends on $m$ and the step $L=\max(M, N)$ is thus incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is only valid under the assumption that $a_{mn} \to b_m$ uniformly for $m \in \mathbb{N}$.

To fix this, note that by the reverse triangle inequality, we have

$$0 \leqslant | \,|a_{mn} - a | - | b_m - a| \, | \leqslant |a_{mn} - b_m| $$
$$\implies 0 \leqslant \lim_{n \to \infty}| \,|a_{mn} - a | - | b_m - a| \, | \leqslant \lim_{n \to \infty}|a_{mn} - b_m| = 0  \\ \implies \lim_{n \to \infty}|a_{mn} - a| = |b_m - a|$$

SInce $|a_{mn} - a| < \epsilon $ for all $m,n > M$, we have for all $m > M$

$$|b_m - a| = \lim_{n \to \infty}|a_{mn} -a |  \leqslant \epsilon,$$

proving $\lim_{m \to \infty} b_m = a$.